# Swift-fatal error: Array index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I fix this code so I no longer get an error. The error I get is fatal error: Array index out of range. The code checks how many "x" and "o" there are in a string

```
var input = "xxxoxoooxoxo"

var inputString = Array(input.characters)

var XString = ""

var OString = ""

for var i = 0; i <= inputString.count; ++i {

    if inputString[i] == "x" {

        XString.append(inputString[i])

    }

    else if inputString[i] == "o" {

        OString.append(inputString[i])

    }

}

if XString.characters.count == OString.characters.count {

    print("equal")

}

else {

    print("Not Equal")

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If your goal is counting, why construct new strings?

Comment: Keep in mind the standard for loop will be deprecated in swift 2.2 and removed in 3.0

Comment: as will `++` and `--` I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
for var i = 0; i <= inputString.count; ++i
```

with this:

```
for var i = 0; i < inputString.count; ++i
```

Arrays are zero indexed. That means the first element has the index 0. The second element has index 1. ... . The last element has the index `array.count-1`.

Answer (score 3):

@dasdom is correct. but here is a more Swift-y way to do it:

```
// input string
var input = "ooooxxxxxxxoxoooxoxo" 

// difference between number of x's and number of o's
var diff = 0 

// perform this function for each character in `input.characters`:
input.characters.forEach {
    switch $0 // $0 is the argument to our function (unnamed)
    {
        case "x": diff += 1          // x's are +1
        case "o": diff -= 1          // o's are -1
        default: fatalError()        // we expect only 'x' or 'o'... if we get something else, just crash
    }
}

// use the ternary (?:) operator to print the answer.
// (<result> = <condition> ? <if-true value> : <if-false value>)
print( diff == 0 ? "equal" : "not equal" )
```

---

A shorter version, inspired by @Eendje's answer :)

```
print( input.characters.reduce(0) { $0 + [ "x":1, "o":-1 ][ $1 ]! } != 0 ? "not" : "", "equal" )
```

Comment: Haha, nice one! I really like the use of a dictionary here. I would use `?? 0` instead of implicitly unwrapping it though :) (Maybe I should add that in my answer! :P)

Comment: The second version is quite interesting, but I think it's to much for someone struggling with the number of elements in an array. ;)

Comment: I used force unwrap to catch "invalid" characters... but if you don't care about that, then `?? 0` works, sure.

Comment: I wonder, lets say `input` has over 1000 characters. How expensive is it to create a dictionary for every iteration? Do you happen to have any idea?

Comment: hopefully, since it's a literal it won't be created every time? but if that's a concern, the dictionary could be created outside the closure...

Comment: I tried it.. Swift isn't that smart. Shorter code to type, but longer time waiting for results. :)

Answer (score 2):

While everyone is giving you an alternative, I thought this would be a nice addition as well:

```
var input = "xxxxxoxoooxoxo"
```

You can get the count by using `filter`:

```
let xCount = input.characters.filter { $0 == "x" }.count
let oCount = input.characters.filter { $0 == "o" }.count

print( xCount == oCount ? "equal" : "not equal" )
```

In your case, using `reduce` would be more efficient and it's shorter:

```
let result = input.characters.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 == "x" ? 1 : -1) }

print(result == 0 ? "equal" : "not equal") // not equal
```

This is only if you're sure `input` only contains `x` and `o`. If not, then you'll have to change the evaluation to:

```
{ $0 + ($1 == "x" ? 1 : $1 == "o" ? -1 : 0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are enumerating pass the range of the array. Use this instead.

```
for var i = 0; i < inputString.count; ++i {
```

Or you can use this more idiomatic code:

```
var input = "xxxoxoooxoxo"


var xString = 0

var oString = 0

for c in input.characters {

    if c == "x" {

        xString++

    }

    else if c == "o" {

        oString++

    }

}

if oString == xString {

    print("equal")

}

else {

    print("Not Equal")

}
```